# Meteor Router with Meteor call

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I having trouble to validate a user with a Meteor.call on Router. Only return "undefined" pr

> "Exception in delivering result of invoking 'verifyUserRole':
>   TypeError: undefined is not a function"

```
Router.route("/admin", function(){
    Meteor.call("verifyUserRole", function(error, result){
        if(result){
            this.render('adminDashboard');
            this.layout("adminLayout");
        } else {
            this.render('adminLogin');
        }
    })
});
```

---

```
 Meteor.methods({
   "verifyUserRole" : function(){
       if(this.userId){
       var user = Meteor.user();
       var role = user.profile.role;
       if(role == "admin"){
           return true;
       } else {
           Session.set("adminLoginError", "Restrict Area");
           return false;
       }
   }
}});
```

Comment: Meteor.call does not return a value on the client: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `this` is referring to your inner function instead of your outer function. Try the following:

```
Router.route("/admin", function(){
  var self = this;
  Meteor.call("verifyUserRole", function(error, result){
    if(result){
      self.render('adminDashboard');
      self.layout("adminLayout");
    } else {
      self.render('adminLogin');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks! Now the trouble is now about how render the page with the if or else, automatically without press F5. I have inserted the line: location.reload(), in the final, but refreshs forever.

Comment: You can check whether the user role is 'admin' without doing a Meteor.call(), just check it client side in the route. The profile field is published automatically. Also it is a good idea to user the 'roles' package for these checks.